# Can intransitive "joked" be used without a preposition before "that" clauses?

Tags: vocabulary

Is the usage of the verb "joked" correct here? Does it need a preposition?

> Reporters joked that  the animal had personal problems with humans, as the number of his attacks was astonishing.

Answer (score 1):

"To joke" can be used without an object, does not require a preposition and means "comment in a non-serious way".

> The commentator joked that his Grandma might have been able to score that one!
>
> The leader of the opposition joked that his counterpart didn't have long left in power!